# AND request in model opencart

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart, opencart2.x

I develop new filter in admin opencart.
But my sql request is don't work

Field "value" is declared in table `oc_order_option`

Sql request without my filter

```
SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.lastname, ' ', o.firstname) AS customer, COUNT(po.pass_id) as passengers, m.name as carrier, cd.name as tour, o.shipping_code, o.total, os.name as order_status, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified 
FROM oc_order o 
LEFT JOIN oc_agent_to_order ato ON ato.order_id = o.order_id
JOIN oc_order_option oo ON oo.order_id = o.order_id 
JOIN oc_order_status os ON os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id 
JOIN oc_passenger_to_order po ON o.order_id = po.order_id 
JOIN oc_passenger pfo ON po.pass_id = pfo.pass_id 
JOIN oc_order_product op ON op.order_id = o.order_id 
JOIN oc_product p ON p.product_id = op.product_id 
JOIN oc_manufacturer m ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id 
JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id AND ptc.main_category = 1 
JOIN oc_category_description cd ON cd.category_id = ptc.category_id 
WHERE o.order_status_id > '0'
```

I try this sql code for my request

```
AND value BETWEEN '10.04.2019' AND '10.04.2019'
```

Full code:

```
SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.lastname, ' ', o.firstname) AS customer, COUNT(po.pass_id) as passengers, m.name as carrier, cd.name as tour, o.shipping_code, o.total, os.name as order_status, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified 
FROM oc_order o 
LEFT JOIN oc_agent_to_order ato ON ato.order_id = o.order_id 
JOIN oc_order_option oo ON oo.order_id = o.order_id 
JOIN oc_order_status os ON os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id 
JOIN oc_passenger_to_order po ON o.order_id = po.order_id 
JOIN oc_passenger pfo ON po.pass_id = pfo.pass_id 
JOIN oc_order_product op ON op.order_id = o.order_id 
JOIN oc_product p ON p.product_id = op.product_id 
JOIN oc_manufacturer m ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id 
JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id AND ptc.main_category = 1 
JOIN oc_category_description cd ON cd.category_id = ptc.category_id 
WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' AND value BETWEEN '10.04.2019' AND '10.04.2019'
```

Comment: i think `10.04.2019` is not a valid format for using `BETWEEN`

Comment: _Column_ value's data type?

Comment: Doesn't work how? Error message, or not the expected result?

Comment: Make it easy/possible to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use a proper date format for the constants?

```
value BETWEEN '2019-04-10' AND '2019-04-10'
```

This is, of course, equivalent to:

```
value = '2019-04-10'
```

If `value` is a date/time value, then this only matches at midnight on 2019-04-10.  I suspect that you might want:

```
value >= '2019-04-10' AND
value < '2019-04-11'
```